# How to use #38cbf8 Color in UIColor in iOS7?

Tags: ios7, uicolor

I am not good at color schema. :D

Of of my friend give me to use this color  `#38cbf8` in my App for `iOS7`.

I don't know how to use that color in `UIColor`.

How do i use it in `UIColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `[UIColor colorWithRed:0x38/255. green:0xcb/255. blue:0xf8/255. alpha:1.0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great tool to use for generating UIColor from hex colors. This tool even auto generates the UIColor code for you.

http://uicolor.org/